# $g: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ such that $\int_{x}^{y} g \leq M(y-x)$ for all $x < y \in [0, 1]$ then $g \leq M$ a.e.

Tags: lebesgue-integral, borel-measures

Let $M > 0$ and let $g: [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be Borel measurable with $\int_{x}^{y} g(x) dx \leq M(y-x)$ for every $x < y \in [0, 1]$. Show $g \leq M$ a.e.

What I tried to do was tinker with $\int_{g > M} g(x) dx$, but I'm not sure how to relate it to the condition above with intervals. Is there a way I can approximate $\{g > M\}$ with intervals? I know I can approximate it with a Borel set (or even a closed set) but this doesn't seem to help! I can also say $g$ is continuous on a set that's close to $[0, 1]$ in measure.

Comment: follows trivially from Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Comment: alternatively, one could argue that if $\{g > M\}$ had positive measure, then $\{g > M+\frac{1}{n}\}$ had positive measure for some $n \ge 1$, and so we could take some point $z \in \{g > M+\frac{1}{n}\}$ that is a point of density of $\{g > M+\frac{1}{n}\}$ and take $x < y$ with $(x,y)$ centered at $z$ and $(x,y) \cap \{g > M+\frac{1}{n}\} > (1-\epsilon)(y-x)$, which would yield $(1-\epsilon)(M+\frac{1}{n})(y-x) \le \int_x^y g(t)dt \le M(y-x)$, a contradiction for small enough $\epsilon > 0$. But the existence of points of density follows from Lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this alternative argument. The result follows immediately from Lebsgue's Theorem so why use points of density?

Comment: I haven't heard of Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem, but I'd like to avoid using it seeing as this question is on a past qualifying exam at my university, and the Measure Theory there doesn't talk about this theorem! However, I think I have an argument, which I'll write up above soon.

Comment: I take that back... I was thinking of showing $\{B \text{ Borel} : \int_{B} g \leq M\mu(B)\}$ is a monotone class or $\sigma$-algebra which contains the Borels. This would give me the bounding property not only for intervals. But then I run into the same problem - perhaps Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem is the only way. Thank you!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy are you objecting generally to giving multiple arguments?

Comment: No. Multiple arguments are most welcome. But existence of density points requires Lebesgue's Theorem. Have you seen an independent proof? @mathworker21

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok, fair point. I have not.